# When an existing composite index may transition to ERROR?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a lot of indices. Some exponential indices too.
I also know that some entities are too big to be indexed.
All the current indices are in a green state.

Under which conditions the indexes may transition to ERROR?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_limits):

> Any commit operation that would cause an index to exceed the index entry or size limit will fail. The text of the error describes which limit was exceeded ("Too many indexed properties" or "Index entries too large") and which custom index was the cause. If you create a new index that would exceed the limits for any entity when built, queries against the index will fail and the index will appear in the Error state in the GCP Console.

If you expect this situation, you might take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#indexes) documentation about best practices with indexes. In addition, as you stated, you have a lot of indexes, therefore there is a high probability that some of them are unused. In that case it would be recommended to [delete unused indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_Deleting_unused_indexes).

Comment: Sorry, but your phrase does not answer the question. I was specifically asking when the indexes are going to transition to the state ERROR, not "what is going to happen to the operations not conforming to index limits"

Comment: I have modified the quote from the documentation, hopefully now is clearer.

Comment: So an existing index will never transition fro READY to ERROR?

Comment: From the quoted text above I understand that if you create an index successfully but at some point this index exceeds the limits for an entity when built, any query against that index will fail and the index will transition to ERROR state. Therefore, an existing index can transition form READY to ERROR state.